# Updating XML file with C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I am building an application that will use textbox input to edit the contents of a xml file.  I have gotten the basic concepts of creating NEW xml files with C#, but I continue to get errors when trying to update a file.  PLEASE.. help?

(I am a new developer who needs a lot of help. Please add comments if I need to post anything else.)

**EDIT:** *This is where my problem is: `doc.CreateElement()`. It will not update the file. If I click the save button, the file itself doesn't update.*

This is what I've tried:

**fileName.xml**:

```
 <ApplicationPreferences>
   <Facility>2400</Facility> 
   <FacilityName>Somewhere</FacilityName> 
 </ApplicationPreferences>
```

**Code**:

```
namespace WIPSControlPanel
{
[Serializable]
public class ApplicationPreferences 
{
    private const string CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "fileName.xml";
    private string _facility = String.Empty;
    private string _facilityName = String.Empty;
    private string _preferencesPath = CONFIG_FILE_NAME;
    private string _appURI = String.Empty;

    [XmlElement]
    public string FacilityName
    {
        get { return _facilityName; }
        set { _facilityName = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Facility
    {
        get { return _facility; }
        set { _facility = value; }
    }

     public string AppURI
    {
        get { return _appURI; }
    }

    //Constructor
    public ApplicationPreferences()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs the class
    /// </summary>
    public ApplicationPreferences(string pathName)
    {

        _preferencesPath = Path.Combine(pathName, CONFIG_FILE_NAME);

    }

   public void Save()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationPreferences));
        XmlWriter writer = GetXmlWriter();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationPreferences));
        XmlReader reader = GetXmlReader();
        ApplicationPreferences newConfig = (ApplicationPreferences)serializer.Deserialize(reader);


        if (newConfig != null)
        {
            this.FacilityName = newConfig.FacilityName;
            this.Facility = newConfig.Facility;
        }
    }

private XmlReader GetXmlReader()
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

        return XmlReader.Create(_preferencesPath, settings);
    }


    private XmlWriter GetXmlWriter()
    {
        if (CONFIG_FILE_NAME != null)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

            return XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"\\server"), CONFIG_FILE_NAME));
        }
    }
 }


namespace WIPSControlPanel
{

   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
    #region Private Variables
    private ApplicationPreferences _configFile = new ApplicationPreferences();
    }

   public ApplicationPreferences ConfigFile
    {
        get { return _configFile; }

        set
        {
            _configFile = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ConfigFile");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += fileLoad;
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.ConfigFile = new ApplicationPreferences(@"\\server");
        this.ConfigFile.Load();
        LoadAvailableOperations(this.ConfigFile.Facility);
        UpdateOperationDescriptions(this.ConfigFile);
    }

    private void butGenSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("WIPSConfig");

        XmlWriter writer;

        XElement newElement = doc.CreateElement(
            new XElement("Facility", txtFacility.Text),
            new XElement("FacilityName", txtFacilityName.Text),
            new XElement("ApplicationStatus", txtStatus.Text),
            (new XElement("RefreshInterval", txtRefreshInterval.Text)));
        doc.Save(writer);

        writer = new XmlTextWriter("WIPSConfig.xml", null);
        writer.WriteStartElement("ApplicationPreferences");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        doc.Save(writer);
        writer.Close();

    }
 }
```

**XAML for textboxes**:

```xaml
 <TextBox x:Name="txtFacilityName"
                                         Grid.Column="1"
                                         Margin="5,5,0,5"
                                         Width="129"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                         Text="{Binding ConfigFile.FacilityName}" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtFacility"
                                         Grid.Column="1"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         Width="129"
                                         Margin="5,5,0,5"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                         Text="{Binding ConfigFile.Facility}" />
```

Comment: What kinds of errors are you getting?

Comment: You cannot assign the result of `System.Xml.CreateElement()` to `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`, they are totally different classes. `LoadXml()` needs an XML string, which "WIPSConfig" certainly is not. You try to create an `XElement` and then throw it away without doing anything with it. Then you try to deserialize an XmlReader, which is not a serializable class. Please tell us what you are trying to achieve, not what you are trying to do, because what you are trying to do makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Off the bat, it looks like you might be creating the file one place and then trying to read it from a different place:

```
// _preferencesPath ~= @"\\srvusadcweb01\wips_test\Cortland\fileName.xml":
XmlReader.Create(_preferencesPath, settings);

XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"\\server"), CONFIG_FILE_NAME));
```

Unless `@"\\server"` was just an edit to make things a bit more "generic".

**EDIT**

Are you trying to using `XmlWriter.Create()` to overwrite an existing file? If so, you may want to check this out:
[C# Serialization to file, overwrite if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064282/c-sharp-serialization-to-file-overwrite-if-exists)

```
XmlWriter.Create(File.Create(fileName), settings)
```

Comment: yeah server was a mask for the name

Comment: In my code, both are the same, just edited to make it generic.

Comment: This is where my problem is.... the doc.CreateElement() It will not update the file.  If I click the save button, the file itself doesn't update.